# Magento2 - How to implement slow loading

Tags: magento2, product, category, lazyload

I want to implement slow loading for my homepage.

My homepage consist of category image then 9 products related to that category.This continues for all categories. For that, I want to implement lazy loading. first by default one category and there products are displayed after that, rest category image and there products are displayed through lazy loading.

I want to know how can I implement lazy loading for this

Comment: You are already using the lazyloading extension you need to add a classname `.lazy` or the classname which you lazyloading extension is using, to all your images of listing on the home page and other section images.

Comment: @RizwanKhan I am not using any kind of extension

Comment: how you have using lazyloading on category image and there products?

Comment: @RizwanKhan I want to do that. that's what i am asking, how to do that\

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free extension.
https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-lazy-load-product-extension.html

By default it will automatically be applied on category and product view page, to apply on custom pages or home page you need to perform below steps:

1. Add the html class `lazy` to the img element.
2. Add the html data-original attribute with the path to the image.
3. Add a loader image in `src` attribute which will be displayed before the image loads.

Example img tag:

```
<img class=“lazy” src=“path/to/loader-image/loading.gif” data-original=“path/to/image/image.jpg” alt=“” />
```

Comment: any option other than plugin. I want to write javascript code

Comment: maybe this can help: https://medium.com/@filipvitas/lazy-load-images-with-zero-javascript-2c5bcb691274

Comment: I dont want to lazy load images. I want to lazy load an either div element